# Arrays? List? Storing Values(x,y) to each line

Tags: python, arrays, storing-data

Is there any way on python to create some sort of an array
to assign an x and y value to every line in a file 
every time it is split?

`myArray=[][]`?

say the lines are

```
0.0 0.0 NaN  ( I want this line to have value[1,1]

1.0 0.0 1.0  (and so increasing y by one leaving x alone [1,2]

2.0 0.0 NaN  ---[1,3]

3.0 0.0 NaN---[1,4]

0.0 1.0 2.0---(but when the middle term changes value (increase x by 1 and reset y to 1 leaving [2,1])

1.0 1.0 3.0---[2,2]

2.0 1.0 4.0---[2,3]

3.0 1.0 NaN--- and so on

0.0 2.0 5.0

1.0 2.0 6.0

2.0 2.0 7.0

3.0 2.0 NaN

0.0 3.0 NaN

1.0 3.0 NaN

2.0 3.0 8.0

3.0 3.0 9.0

0.0 4.0 NaN

1.0 4.0 NaN

2.0 4.0 NaN

3.0 4.0 10.0  ---[4,4]
```

Does this make sense of what I am asking?
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `(number of 0.0 in column 1, count of rows after the last 0.0 in column 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
text = """0.0 0.0 NaN

1.0 0.0 1.0

2.0 0.0 NaN

3.0 0.0 NaN

0.0 1.0 2.0

1.0 1.0 3.0

2.0 1.0 4.0

3.0 1.0 NaN

0.0 2.0 5.0

1.0 2.0 6.0

2.0 2.0 7.0

3.0 2.0 NaN

0.0 3.0 NaN

1.0 3.0 NaN

2.0 3.0 8.0

3.0 3.0 9.0

0.0 4.0 NaN"""

# read data

results = []
for x in text.splitlines():
    x = x.strip()
    if x:
        results.append( x.split() ) 

# count [1,1], [1,2], etc.

new_results = []

value = [0,0]
middle = None

for row in results:
    if row[1] != middle:
        middle = row[1]
        value[0] += 1
        value[1] = 1
    row.append(value[:])
    new_results.append(row)
    value[1] += 1

for x in new_results:
    print x
```

result:

```
['0.0', '0.0', 'NaN', [1, 1]]
['1.0', '0.0', '1.0', [1, 2]]
['2.0', '0.0', 'NaN', [1, 3]]
['3.0', '0.0', 'NaN', [1, 4]]
['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', [2, 1]]
['1.0', '1.0', '3.0', [2, 2]]
['2.0', '1.0', '4.0', [2, 3]]
['3.0', '1.0', 'NaN', [2, 4]]
['0.0', '2.0', '5.0', [3, 1]]
['1.0', '2.0', '6.0', [3, 2]]
['2.0', '2.0', '7.0', [3, 3]]
['3.0', '2.0', 'NaN', [3, 4]]
['0.0', '3.0', 'NaN', [4, 1]]
['1.0', '3.0', 'NaN', [4, 2]]
['2.0', '3.0', '8.0', [4, 3]]
['3.0', '3.0', '9.0', [4, 4]]
['0.0', '4.0', 'NaN', [5, 1]]
```